# Is there any way to "free" the Doctrine2 QueryBuilder object?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I am running into an interesting issue and now I am curious about the "why". Maybe this Doctrine2 related, maybe it's not, maybe is just OOP.

Take a look to the following Doctrine Repository function:

```
public function generateOrderPush(int $quote_id): array
{
    $group_quote_id = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('QuoteBundle:Quote')->find($quote_id)->getGroupQuoteId();

    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

    $header = $qb->select(['q.quoteId','q.othersQuoteId','IDENTITY(q.distributor)'])
                 ->from('QuoteBundle:Quote', 'q')
                 ->where('q.quoteType =:quote_type')
                 ->andWhere('q.groupQuoteId =:group_quote_id')
                 ->setParameter('quote_type', 'current')
                 ->setParameter('group_quote_id', $group_quote_id)
                 ->setMaxResults(1)
                 ->orderBy('q.quoteId', 'ASC')
                 ->getQuery()
                 ->getArrayResult();

    $details = $qb->select(['qt.quoteId', 'qt.othersQuoteId', 'IDENTITY(qt.customer)'])
                  ->from('QuoteBundle:Quote', 'qt')
                  ->join('QuoteBundle:QuoteDetail', 'qd', 'WITH', 'qt.quoteId = qd.quoteId')
                  ->where('qt.quoteType =:quote_type')
                  ->andWhere('qt.groupQuoteId =:group_quote_id')
                  ->setParameter('quote_type', 'current')
                  ->setParameter('group_quote_id', $group_quote_id)
                  ->groupBy('qd.renewalPartNumber')
                  ->orderBy('qt.quoteId', 'ASC')
                  ->getQuery()
                  ->getArrayResult();

    return [];
}
```

The first query `$header` is executed properly and I got data back. The second query `$details` is failing as error below show:

> SELECT q0_.quote_id AS quote_id_0, q0_.QuoteID AS QuoteID_1,
>   q0_.CustomerSiteID AS sclr_2, FROM quote q1_ INNER JOIN quote_detail
>   q2_ ON (q0_.quote_id = q2_.quote_id), quote q0_ WHERE q0_.quote_type =
>   ? AND q0_.group_quote_id = ? GROUP BY q2_.RenewalPartNumber ORDER BY
>   q0_.quote_id ASC LIMIT 1' with params ["current", 1428]:
>
> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'q0_.quote_id' in 
>   'on clause'

I think somehow Doctrine keep|think I am referring to the first object (from previous) query when I am not since I have added a new alias for the second query `qt`.

A solution to the issue could be split this into two different functions but before get into that one, I would like to know why is this happening and if there is any other way than mine to fix the problem.

Comment: You showed a sort of raw query as a thrown error with no error message!

Comment: @revo upss, added to the OP ..

Comment: You're missing a `'` in your 2d select, it's normal?

Comment: Does using another queryBuilder object could help?

Comment: @Veve the missing `'` is a typo and I'll give a try to a second QB object.

Comment: @Veve use different QB objects make it to work properly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a different queryBuilder object:

```
public function generateOrderPush(int $quote_id): array
{
    $group_quote_id = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('QuoteBundle:Quote')->find($quote_id)->getGroupQuoteId();

    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
    $anotherQb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

    $header = $qb->select(['q.quoteId','q.othersQuoteId','IDENTITY(q.distributor)'])
                 ->from('QuoteBundle:Quote', 'q')
                 ->where('q.quoteType =:quote_type')
                 ->andWhere('q.groupQuoteId =:group_quote_id')
                 ->setParameter('quote_type', 'current')
                 ->setParameter('group_quote_id', $group_quote_id)
                 ->setMaxResults(1)
                 ->orderBy('q.quoteId', 'ASC')
                 ->getQuery()
                 ->getArrayResult();

    $details = $anotherQb->select(['qt.quoteId', 'qt.othersQuoteId', 'IDENTITY(qt.customer)'])
                  ->from('QuoteBundle:Quote', 'qt')
                  ->join('QuoteBundle:QuoteDetail', 'qd', 'WITH', 'qt.quoteId = qd.quoteId')
                  ->where('qt.quoteType =:quote_type')
                  ->andWhere('qt.groupQuoteId =:group_quote_id')
                  ->setParameter('quote_type', 'current')
                  ->setParameter('group_quote_id', $group_quote_id)
                  ->groupBy('qd.renewalPartNumber')
                  ->orderBy('qt.quoteId', 'ASC')
                  ->getQuery()
                  ->getArrayResult();

    return [];
}
```